# in array with mysql fetch object

Tags: mysql, arrays, object, fetch

Hi gus this is my first question in this coumunity i hope someone answer me

when i want to search from array of mysql_fetch_arrray he give me on error

this is the code

```
$key = "Meca";
$query = "SELECT * FROM subject WHERE  `name` LIKE '%$key%' Or `sale` LIKE '%$key%' Or `Emphet` LIKE '%$key%' ";

$sql = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);

while ($num >0)
       {

          $row = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
          $num--;
          $row = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
          in_array($row , "Meca");

       }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear with your question;

Anyway I give a try:

```
$key = "Meca"; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM subject WHERE name LIKE '%$key%' Or sale LIKE '%$key%' Or Emphet LIKE '%$key%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          if(in_array($row , "Meca")){
               echo "$key is present this time."
          }
}
```

Note that:

- I am not on your requirement. So I just make a rough sketch.
- You have not provided your error message.
- You may have error in your code(SQl or PHP)[like usage of names
  'Emphet'].

Anyway give a try.

Comment: Have you really gone? Expecting a response to this answer.